# How calculate size of RSA cipher text using key size & clear text length?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, polarssl

I've some clear text which I want to encrypt using RSA_PKCS_V21 (using PolarSSL library). The problem is that I need to know size of cipher text before executing the algorithm (for dynamic memory allocation purpose).
I know RSA key size & clear text length.
I also want to know the limitation on input clear text length.
Any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just check the [RSA PKCS#1 v2.1 standard, chapter 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.2):

> RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5-ENCRYPT ((n, e), M)
>
> Input:
>
> - (n, e)   recipient's RSA public key (k denotes the length in octets
>   of the modulus n)
> - M        message to be encrypted, an octet string of length mLen,
>   where **mLen <= k - 11**

So the input depends on the key size. `k` is that key size but in octets. So for a 1024 bit key you have 1024 / 8 - 11 = 117 bytes as maximum plain text.

---

Note that above is the maximum size for RSA with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. For the newer OAEP padding the following can be found in [chapter 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.1):

> RSAES-OAEP-ENCRYPT ((n, e), M, L)
>
> ...
>
> Input:

> - (n, e)   recipient's RSA public key (k denotes the length in octets
>   of the RSA modulus n)
> - M        message to be encrypted, an octet string of length mLen,
>   where **mLen <= k - 2hLen - 2**
> - L        optional label to be associated with the message; the
>   default value for L, if L is not provided, is the empty
>   string

Where hLen is the output size of the hash function used for the mask generation function. If the default SHA-1 hash function is used then the maximum size of the message is k - 42 (as the output size of SHA-1 is 20 bytes, and 2 * 20 + 2 = 42).

---

Normally a randomly generated secret key is encrypted instead of the message. Then the message is encrypted with that secret key. This allows almost infinitely long messages, and symmetric crypto - such as AES in CBC mode - is much faster than asymmetric crypto. This combination is called [hybrid encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

---

The output size for RSA encryption or signature generation with any padding is identical to the size of the modulus *in bytes* (rounded upwards, of course), so for a 1024 bit key you would expect 1024 / 8 = 128 octets / bytes.

Note that the output array of the calculated size may contain leading bytes set to zero; this should be considered normal.

Comment: This is a fairly old question, but since I just stumbled upon it while researching part of the question: I think this answer does not answer the entire question, which also asks for the expected size of the *ciphertext*, not only the limitations on the input size. i.e., given a 2048 bit RSA key, how large is the generated *ciphertext* given a specific cleartext message? This question was not addressed by your answer (or I missed it).

Comment: @malexmave Added another section to the answer. Forgot about it as it is kind of obvious. **Warning** the 1024 bit key size is just an example, using a 2048 bit key size or higher is strongly recommended.