# Source text, key size relationship for encryption/decryption in Go

Tags: encryption, go, cryptography, aes, rsa

In the code below (also at http://play.golang.org/p/77fRvrDa4A but takes "too long to process" in the browser there) the 124 byte version of the **sourceText** won't encrypt because: "message too long for RSA public key size" of 1024. It, and the longer 124 byte **sourceText** version, work with 2048 bit key size.

My question is how does one exactly calculate the key size in **rsa.GenerateKey** given the byte length of the source text? (A small paragraph size of text takes nearly 10 seconds at 4096 key size, and I don't know the length of the sourceText until runtime.)

There's a very brief discussion of this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11750658/3691075, but it's not clear to me as I'm not a crypto guy.

My goal is to encrypt, store in a DB and decrypt about 300-byte long JSON strings. I control both the sending and the receiving end. Text is encrypted once, and decrypted many times. Any hints of strategy would be appreciated.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "fmt"
    "hash"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
     startingTime := time.Now()
     var err error
     var privateKey *rsa.PrivateKey
     var publicKey *rsa.PublicKey
     var sourceText, encryptedText, decryptedText, label []byte

    // SHORT TEXT 92 bytes
     sourceText = []byte(`{347,7,3,8,7,0,7,5,6,4,1,6,5,6,7,3,7,7,7,6,5,3,5,3,3,5,4,3,2,10,3,7,5,6,65,350914,760415,33}`)
     fmt.Printf("\nsourceText byte length:\n%d\n", len(sourceText))

    // LONGER TEXT 124 bytes
    // sourceText = []byte(`{347,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,65,350914,760415,33}`)
    // fmt.Printf("\nsourceText byte length:\n%d\n", len(sourceText))

    if privateKey, err = rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 1024); err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // fmt.Printf("\nprivateKey:\n%s\n", privateKey)

    privateKey.Precompute()

    if err = privateKey.Validate(); err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
    }

     publicKey = &privateKey.PublicKey

     encryptedText = encrypt(publicKey, sourceText, label)
     decryptedText = decrypt(privateKey, encryptedText, label)

     fmt.Printf("\nsourceText: \n%s\n", string(sourceText))
     fmt.Printf("\nencryptedText: \n%x\n", encryptedText)
     fmt.Printf("\ndecryptedText: \n%s\n", decryptedText)

     fmt.Printf("\nDone in %v.\n\n", time.Now().Sub(startingTime))
}

func encrypt(publicKey *rsa.PublicKey, sourceText, label []byte) (encryptedText []byte) {
     var err error
     var md5_hash hash.Hash
     md5_hash = md5.New()
     if encryptedText, err = rsa.EncryptOAEP(md5_hash, rand.Reader,           publicKey, sourceText, label); err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
     }
     return
}

func decrypt(privateKey *rsa.PrivateKey, encryptedText, label []byte) (decryptedText []byte) {
     var err error
     var md5_hash hash.Hash
     md5_hash = md5.New()
     if decryptedText, err = rsa.DecryptOAEP(md5_hash, rand.Reader, privateKey, encryptedText, label); err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
     }
     return
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One does not usually calculate the RSA key size based on payload. One simply needs to select one RSA key size based on a compromise between security (bigger is better) and performance (smaller is better). If that is done, use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) in conjunction with AES or another symmetric cipher to actually encrypt the data.

If the payload doesn't exceed 300 bytes and you're using OAEP (at least 42 bytes of padding), then you can easily calculate the minimum key size:

```
(300 + 42) * 8 = 2736 bit
```

That's already a reasonable size key. It provides good security according to today's norms and is fairly fast. There is no need to apply a hybrid encryption scheme for this.

Now, you may notice that the key size isn't a power of 2. [This is not a problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/7849/why-are-rsa-key-sizes-almost-always-a-power-of-two). You should however use a key size that is a multiple of 64 bit, because processors use 32-bit and 64-bit primitives to do the actual calculation, so you can increase the security without a performance penalty. The next such key size would be:

```
ceil((300 + 42) * 8 / 64.0) * 64 = 2752 bit
```

Here are some experimental results what some languages/frameworks accept (not performance-wise) as the key size:

- Golang: multiple of 1 bit and >= 1001 (sic!) [used ideone.com]
- PyCrypto: multiple of 256 bit and >= 1024 [local install]
- C#: multiple of 16 bit and >= 512 [used ideone.com]
- Groovy: multiple of 1 bit and >= 512 [local install]
- Java: multiple of 1 bit and >= 512 [used ideone.com: Java & Java7]
- PHP/OpenSSL Ext: multiple of 128 bit and >= 640 [used ideone.com]
- Crypto++: multiple of 1 bit and >= 16 [local install with maximal validation toughness of `3`]

Before you decide to use some kind of specific key size, you should check that all frameworks support that size. As you see, there are vastly varying results.

I tried to write some performance tests of key generation, encryption and decryption with different key sizes: 512, 513, 514, 516, 520, 528, 544, 576. Since I don't know any go, it would be hard to get the timing right. So I settled for Java and Crypto++. The Crypto++ code is probably very buggy, because key generation for 520-bit and 528-bit keys is up to seven orders of magnitude faster than for the other key sizes which is more or less constant for the small key size window.

In Java the key generation was pretty clear in that the generation of a 513-bit key was 2-3 *times* slower than for a 512-bit key. Other than that the results are nearly linear. The graph is normalized and the numbers of iterations is 1000 for the full keygen-enc-dec cycle.

[image: key generation, encryption and decryption performance for different key sizes]

The decryption makes a little dip at 544-bit which is a multiple of 32-bit. Since it was executed on a 32-bit debian, this might mean that indeed there are some performance improvements, but on the other hand the encryption was slower for that key size.

Since this benchmark wasn't done in Go, I won't give any advice on how small the overhead can be.

Comment: Sorry, that last paragraph is simply incorrect. I felt it must be incorrect and I've tested it with Java just to be sure (so I've to eat fast otherwise my healthy green beans are getting cold).

Comment: Just to be 100% compatibility with existing implementations I would use a multiple of 64 bit or even 3072 (2048 + 1024, so 2^x + 2^(x-1)). Note that some (hardware) runtimes are restricted to 2048 bits as well.

Comment: Maarten, your two comments are somewhat contradictory. First you say that my last paragraph is wrong (I suspect you mean the multiple of 64-bit), then you say that a multiple of 64-bit is ok. It's kind of strange. Maybe you can clarify what you meant. In any case I used your critique to do a little experimentation and the results are vastly different across languages/frameworks. I also wanted to do Ruby and PhpSecLib, but ruby was buggy on ideone and I couldn't get phpseclib to download from sourceforge.

Comment: There is a clear performance difference between e.g. 1025/1057 bits and 1088 bits on the Java platform. For 1000 iterations I got an average of 4.744/4.874 ms and 5.150 ms. However, an 8 byte difference is a *very* good idea for compatibility reasons. And using anything else than something on the byte boundary is just asking for trouble.

Comment: PyCrypto is certainly taking it a bit too far. 32 *byte* steps? That's fine for a protocol, but not for the underlying primitive. Personally I think for an API 8 bit steps are fine, but 1 bit steps are still preferable.

Comment: I want to vote up, but the performance remark is still in there. Test on the other frameworks as well for the performance. You'll see that in the majority of cases the performance will go down for each bit of security that is added (my apologies to your CPU, it'll get hammered generating the key pairs :) ).

Comment: I actually haven't *yet* run a performace test on the different key sizes. That was just a check what sizes are accepted at all. :)